# Checking session variables with empty() and isset() in CodeIgniter 3.x

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

With CodeIgniter 3.0.3, the documentation states that session data can be retrieved a few different ways, including `$_SESSION['item']` and `$this->session->item`. It's true. No matter how I set the session variable, I see that I can echo the value both ways.

Now, with that session variable populated, I can check for empty condition like this: `if(empty($_SESSION['item']))`, and it evaluates as `bool(false)` just as I would expect. However, if I check the same session variable in this manner: `if(empty($this->session->item))` it evaluates as `bool(true)`, which is NOT what I expect (since I can echo its value on the very next line). Why are these two different ways of checking for empty condition being evaluated differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how empty() works. Compare this quote:

> The result for empty($registry->notEmpty) is a bit unexpeced as the value is obviously set and non-empty. This is due to the fact that the empty() function uses __isset() magic functin in these cases. Although it's noted in the documentation above, I think it's worth mentioning in more detail as the behaviour is not straightforward. In order to achieve desired (expexted?) results, you need to add  __isset() magic function to your class:

(taken from php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php, comment from user Janci)

Comment: Wow. That is strange behavior. If the variable has a value (and especially a scalar value) that can be echoed to the screen, it's kind of scary that the `empty()` function sees it as empty.